# Format Snakemake Input Files in the Shell

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pipeline, snakemake

I'm using a `snakemake` pipeline to run the GATK `MarkDuplicate` command with multiple input bam files from different read groups.

```
rule mark_duplicates:
    input:
        get_dedup_input
    output:
        bam=temp("bams/{patient}.{sample_type}.markdups.bam"),
        md5=temp("bams/{patient}.{sample_type}.markdups.bam.md5"),
        metrics="qc/gatk/{patient}_{sample_type}_dup_metrics.txt"
    conda:
        "../envs/gatk.yml"
    shell:
        """
        gatk MarkDuplicates -I {input} -O {output.bam} -M {output.metrics} \
            --CREATE_MD5_FILE true --ASSUME_SORT_ORDER "queryname"
        """
```

`get_dedup_input` returns a list of input bam files. `MarkDuplicates` requires each input file is specified with the `-I` flag. If I only had one bam file, I could simply write `-I {input}`,
but this fails because this specifies `-I file1.bam file2.bam` it needs to be `-I file1.bam -I file2.bam`. What's the best way to format the input so that each input file is specified as `-I [input file]`?

Here are two scenarios below to clarify what the input, output, and shell commands would look like if I were to run the command manually. I've omitted some of the non-essential `MarkDuplicate` flags for brevity:

#### One Read Group

```
Inputs: patient101.normal.rg1.bam
Output: patient101.normal.markdups.bam
Shell: 
gatk MarkDuplicates -I patient101.normal.rg1.bam \
-O patient101.normal.markdups.bam \
-M metrics.txt
```

#### Two Read Groups

```
Inputs: patient101.normal.rg1.bam, patient101.normal.rg2.bam
Output: patient101.normal.markdups.bam
Shell: 
gatk MarkDuplicates -I patient101.normal.rg1.bam \
-I patient101.normal.rg2.bam \
-O patient101.normal.markdups.bam \
-M metrics.txt
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of which input and which output you expect from this rule?

Comment: Post updated to show an example with the input and output files and the way the command should be run!

Comment: I'm in the train right now, but when I arrive I'll post an answer(if someone else didn't already :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your answer.

So probably the best thing to do is to is make a parameter that becomes the string we need, like so:

```
rule mark_duplicates:
    input:
        get_dedup_input
    output:
        bam=temp("bams/{patient}.{sample_type}.markdups.bam"),
        md5=temp("bams/{patient}.{sample_type}.markdups.bam.md5"),
        metrics="qc/gatk/{patient}_{sample_type}_dup_metrics.txt"
    conda:
        "../envs/gatk.yml"
    params:
        input=lambda wildcards, input: " -I ".join(input)
    shell:
        """
        gatk MarkDuplicates -I {params.input} -O {output.bam} -M {output.metrics} \
            --CREATE_MD5_FILE true --ASSUME_SORT_ORDER "queryname"
        """
```

If our input is a single bam, `params.input` will just be `patient101.normal.rg1.bam` and the `-I` is added in front as normal.

If we have two input bams, our lambda function puts the `-I` in between them and the shell command adds the `-I` in front.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea! After some quick testing it looks like params.input is `file1.bam -I file2.bam` when the string needs to be `-I file1.bam -I file2.bam`. Modifying the lambda to `input=lambda wildcards, input: [" -I  " + f for f in input]` fixes the issue. Could you modify your solution with the updated lambda so I can mark it as correct? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sure, but the -I in the shell command should catch that right?